# Are there any Node packages for handling chunked uploads with Express?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, chunked

I see quite a few articles on how to handle chunked file uploading via Node and Express; for example:

- https://scribie.com/blog/2014/09/chunked-upload-with-nginx-and-nodejs/
- http://www.componentix.com/blog/13/file-uploads-using-nodejs-once-again

This seems like a lot of work. Surely there are Node packages available which make it simple to handle chunked uploads? I've looked on NPM but haven't found anything of the sort. I'd like to just upload to my own server and not to a remote file store like S3.

Answer (score -2):

i think you can handle chunk upload in express without needing any module

```
app.post('/anyUrl', function(req, res){
    var size = 0;

    req.on('data', function (data) {
        size += data.length;
        console.log('Got chunk: ' + data.length + ' total: ' + size);
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log("total size = " + size);
        res.send("response");
    }); 

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR ERROR: " + e.message);
    });


});
```

you can try the obove code making post requests

var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
    fs.createReadStream('path/to/file').pipe(request.post('http://localhost:3000/anyUrl'));

Comment: While this does provide access to the data with each chunked upload, it does not provide a way to deal with boundaries.

Comment: Downvoted because of Chad's comment, this does not address the actual chunking protocol in HTTP you should be looking at HTTP Headers letting you know which bytes are being sent, not assume they arrive in order. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests